# In Spring Boot i have a Async call and I have to wait my next thread to wait till CRUD Operation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, executorservice

In my project .. I have an method `createUserRespone()` which is used to send the response to user and before the there is an Async call which do some database operation and in `createUserRespone()` method I am fetching the value from DB and while fetching the data I want to check if the values are dump in DB or not

Example:

```
// here importScore is AN Async method
irResponse = scoreManager.importScore(fileUpload, loggedInUser);

CreateUserResponse response= this.createUserRespone( a, b);


private CreateUserResponse  createUserRespone(String a, Object b){

    // here I am fetching those values which are inserted from Async method call

}
```

My question

1. How I can validate values are inserted in DB by an Async method
   call in my `createUserRespone()` method.
2. How can we achieve it with Executor Framework or any other
   alternative will also appreciate ??

Please don't say make it a synchronous call

Comment: Well if importScore returns a future, you can block until the future is resolved and create the response then.

Comment: Why "Please don't say make it a synchronous call"?

Comment: Agree with @Mateusz here. Synchronous vs Asynchronous is also driven based on your requirements. If you have to send a response to the user that needs the DB operation to be complete - it is absolutely fine to do it synchronously. If the data update is too huge, then you probably have to change your design accordingly.

Comment: @Mateusz because the  Async method is been called from multiple classes thought the application and making synchronous call might throw an timeout issue

Comment: 1. If it is called from another places that require @Async you could refactor your code to expose both behaviors. 
2. If timeout is your concern then you should rethink your architecture - just making this method Async and then trying to synchronize in some other fashion won't solve your problem. Effectively your call is still synchronous. 
You still did not convince me that it can't be solved synchronously. You would need to elaborate more.

Answer (score 1):

You need some handle on which you can wait. Either the first method has to return a `Future`, or it has to return a `Thread` which it is using to execute the task. (Wait by using `Future.get` or `Thread.join`).

If the first method cannot return any handle, you have to do some polling in the DB and wait in a loop until the expected change in data has occurred.